# Auto send SMS with GPS location

Tags: android, gps, smsmanager

I'm developing an app to send user location via `SMS` after a fixed time.
    I have almost accomplished my task. I'm only facing problem when `GPS` location is not get `SMS` is sent but when i on `GPS` the sending sms is not working.

```
String myAddress = "";

List<Address> location;
private void getAddress() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



     try {

    startService(new Intent(mContext,GPSTracker.class));
    GPSTracker tracker = new GPSTracker(mContext);

    location = tracker.getGeocoderAddress(mContext);  

    if (tracker.canGetLocation() == false) 
       {
        tracker.showSettingsAlert();
       }
       else 
       {
           GlobalValues.location_home_lat = tracker.getLongitude();
           GlobalValues.location_home_lng = tracker.getLatitude();

       }


  if(location != null) {
   Address returnedAddress = location.get(0);
   StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("location:\t");
   for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
   }
   myAddress = strReturnedAddress.toString();



  }




private void countdownStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    detectionStart.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    detectionStart.start();

    detectionStart.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - detectionStart.getBase();
                Date date = new Date(elapsedMillis);
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("s");
                String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
                detectionStart.setText(dateFormatted);

            if(elapsedMillis>THRESHOLD){
                if(userNumber.length()>0 && message.length()>0){
                sendSms(userNumber,message);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                            "Error in sendind sms", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                stopAlarm();
                onCloseActivity();
                goMainActivity();
            }
        }
    });
}


protected void sendSms(String number, String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
     String SENT = "android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT";
     String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

     PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DoorbellDetectedActivity.this, 0,
             new Intent(SENT), 0);

         PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DoorbellDetectedActivity.this, 0,
             new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);


    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(userNumber, null, message, null, null);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    final LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        final LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        final Location location = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
        mc=mapview.getController();
        mc.setZoom(18);
        mlo=new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapview);
        mapview.getOverlays().add(mlo);
        mapview.invalidate();   
        }




        public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

        {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location)
        {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        }

        private void updateWithNewLocation(final Location location)
        {
        mapview=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        String latLongString;
        TextView myLocationText;
        myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        String addressString = "No address found";

        if ( location != null )
        {
        final double lat = location.getLatitude();
        final double lng = location.getLongitude();

        latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
        final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        addressString = String.format("%f, %f", latitude, longitude);
        }
        catch ( final IOException e )
        {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
        }
        else
        {
        latLongString = "No location found";
        }
        myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
 addressString);


        }





        @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MenuInflater inf = getMenuInflater();
            inf.inflate(R.menu.newmenu, menu);
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            String tv1; 
            TextView myLocationText;
            myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            tv1= myLocationText.getText().toString(); 
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", tv1); 
            sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(sendIntent); 
            return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
       }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are doing wrong. Where did the countdown timer started? You should send SMS only when you get the location.that means you should move your code into onlocationchanged () callback of GPStracker class. Please relook into the code your SMS sending logic is not tied with location callbacks rather they are tied to a timer.

Comment: countdown timer started after getting the location. and i have to send sms after 6 countdown